# Wordpress display difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, widget, prettyphoto

I hope someone can assist me please. I am using a "pullout" widget in Wordpress to display a an inline "link" to open certain text in prettyPhoto box which needs to include scrollbars.

This is working perfectly in Google Chrome, however when I display the page in Firefox, it includes all the text of the textbox inside the pullour tab, and does not hide it until the link is clicked?

In the css I have used:

```
.hide
{
display:none;
}
```

Here is the code for my widget:

```
<a href="#inline-1" rel="prettyPhoto" >Link</a>
    <div id="inline-1" class="hide">
        <p>Text to appear in prettyPhoto textbox when the Link is clicked



</p></div>
    </div>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the CSS rule for the element `#inline-1`, if any. If `display:block;` is set on `#inline-1`, it will override the `display:none;` of the `.hide` class, because CSS rules by ID have more specificity than rules by class.

To do this you can use a tool such as Firebug for Firefox.

Furthermore, the prettyPhoto plugin may be modifying the display of the #inline-1 div, causing it to show.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I do not seem to see any display:block - in the css?  however, when I "inspect element" in Chrome, I see a "display:block" which is crossed out?

Comment: yes, the display:block; is crossed out because the display:none; is overriding it. You should try inspecting the element with Firebug on Firefox to see what's going on. You can also disable the plug-in and go with pure CSS to see what's going on.